# Quarkus REST Service returning empty response if wrongly called

Tags: quarkus

I'd like to know if there's a way to return a sort of "REST Service not found" if I try to call a REST API (defined in Quarkus) from the command line. For example:

```
@GET
@Path("/service01")
public String service01()
{
   // Do something
}
```

In this case, if I try to reach the service from curl with:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/service02
```

Then an empty response is returned. Can I configure the REST Endpoint to return a sort of "REST Service not available. Services available :service01, service03..etc"

Comment: Which Quarkus extensions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have in the rest of your code but if this is your only endpoint, you should get a 404 for `/service02` not an empty response.